# Divide list into two list

Tags: kotlin

Is there a simple way to divide list of `Double` into two lists of pairs in Kotlin?

In such way:

```
[x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3] => [(x1, x2), (x2, x3), (x3, x1)], [(y1, y2), (y2, y3), (y3, y1)]
```

I tried to use `filterIndexed` and `zipWithNext`

```
val x = filterIndexed { index, _ -> index % 2 == 0 }.zipWithNext()
val y = filterIndexed { index, _ -> index % 2 == 1 }.zipWithNext()
```

But the result is:

```
[x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3] => [(x1, x2), (x2, x3)], [(y1, y2), (y2, y3)]
```

Comment: Looks like you can just copy the first two elements to the end of the list and this method will work.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, the problem with the `zipWithNext` that you are using is that it doesn't "wrap around", i.e. output the final (x3, x1) or (y3, y1) pair, containing the last and first elements of the list.

You can fix this by simply declaring your own version of `zipWithNext` that does do this.

You can either do something like this:

```
fun <T> Iterable<T>.zipWithNextAndWrapAround(): List<Pair<T, T>> {
    val zippedWithNext = zipWithNext()
    if (zippedWithNext.isEmpty()) return zippedWithNext
    return zippedWithNext + (zippedWithNext.last().second to zippedWithNext.first().first)
}
```

Or copy and paste over the original source code of [`zipWithNext`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/30788566012c571aa1d3590912468d1ebe59983d/libraries/stdlib/common/src/generated/_Collections.kt#L3463) and slightly modify it:

```
fun <T> Iterable<T>.zipWithNextAndWrapAround(): List<Pair<T, T>> {
    val iterator = iterator()
    if (!iterator.hasNext()) return emptyList()
    val result = mutableListOf<Pair<T, T>>()
    var current = iterator.next()

    // remember what the first element was
    val first = current
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        val next = iterator.next()
        result.add(current to next)
        current = next
    }

    // at last, add this pair
    result.add(current to first)
    return result
}
```

Usage:

```
val x = list.filterIndexed { index, _ -> index % 2 == 0 }.zipWithNextAndWrapAround()
val y = list.filterIndexed { index, _ -> index % 2 == 1 }.zipWithNextAndWrapAround()
```

Note that this is looping through the list twice. You can avoid that by writing your own version of [`partition`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/partition.html) called `partitionIndexed`.

The code could be something like:

```
inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.partitionIndexed(predicate: (Int, T) -> Boolean): Pair<List<T>, List<T>> {
    val first = ArrayList<T>()
    val second = ArrayList<T>()
    forEachIndexed { index, element ->
        if (predicate(index, element)) {
            first.add(element)
        } else {
            second.add(element)
        }
    }
    return Pair(first, second)
}

// usage:
val (x, y) = list.partitionIndexed { index, _ -> 
    index % 2 == 0 
}.let { (a, b) ->
    a.zipWithNextAndWrapAround() to b.zipWithNextAndWrapAround()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
val lst = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)

val intermediate = lst.chunked(2).map { it[0] to it[1] }.let { it + it[0] }
val x = intermediate.map { it.first }.zipWithNext()
val y = intermediate.map { it.second }.zipWithNext()

println(x) //[(1, 3), (3, 5), (5, 7), (7, 1)]
println(y) //[(2, 4), (4, 6), (6, 8), (8, 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val input = listOf("x1", "y1", "x2", "y2", "x3", "y3")

val result = list
  .withIndex()
  .groupBy { it.index % 2 }
  .map { entry -> entry.value.map { it.value } }
  .map { (it + it[0]).zipWithNext() }

println(result)
```

Output:

```
[[(x1, x2), (x2, x3), (x3, x1)], [(y1, y2), (y2, y3), (y3, y1)]]
```